# Use Mongoexport to export a collection in multiple files

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to export all datas from one of my collection but the collection exceed 16mo. 
So when I try to re import it, Mongo fails since the limit of import is 16mo.

Is there a way to ask the export in multiple files? I don't find this information in the doc.

Thank you.

Comment: what's an "mo"?  there is no limit on collection size - whatever units 16mo represent.

Comment: sorry, mb (mo is french) and there is a limit in the size of the file you import.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the data in your collection, one possible solution might be to use the `--query <JSON>, -q <JSON>` flag to create several files. ([Documentation here.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--query)) For example, if your collection stores college student documents, e.g.:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5237258211f41a0c647c47b1"),
  name: "Jane Doe",
  age: 19,
  grade: "sophomore" },
{ _id: ObjectId("5237258211f41a0c647c47b2"),
  name: "John Smith",
  age: 20,
  grade: "junior" },
...
```

You might, for example, decide to query on `grade`, running `mongoexport` four times to create four files (freshman, sophomore, junior, senior). If each file was under 16mb, this would solve your problem.

If this doesn't answer your question, please provide the commands you're using to import and export. :)